# C# convert a list of numbers to negative

Tags: c#, arrays, list

How to convert a list of numbers to negative in a single line ?
I also want to know if what I'm doing is correct and if anyone has suggestions to improve it.

I'm trying to generate a circle with a given radius. I used lists to store x and y and so not entirely sure if this is the best way to do it. Also the comment below is where i want the negative numbers.

```
    private static void Generate_Circle(double x0, double y0, double radius)
    {
        double y, r2;
        double x;
        r2 = (radius * radius);
        List<double> xList = new List<double>();
        List<double> yList = new List<double>();
        for (x = -radius; x <= radius; x += radius / 10)
        {
            y = Math.Sqrt(r2 - x * x);
            xList.Add(x);
            yList.Add(y);
        }
        List<double> xxList = new List<double>();
        xxList.AddRange(xList);
        xList.Reverse();
        xxList.AddRange(xList);
        List<double> yyList = new List<double>();
        yyList.AddRange(yList); // This should be converted to negative values
        yList.Reverse();
        yyList.AddRange(yList);

        for (int i = 0; i < xxList.Count; i++) // Loop through List with for
        {
            Console.WriteLine(xxList[i] + " " + yyList[i]);
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
List<double> reversed = yList.Select(x => -x).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Select` extension to do the calculation for each value. WHen you say "convert to negative", I assume that all values are originally positive so that you can simply change the sign:

```
yyList.AddRange(yList.Select(n => -n));
```

---

An alternative to duplicating and reversing the values would be to just use the values twice, then you don't have to create the second sets of lists at all:

```
for (int i = 0; i < xList.Count; i++) {
  Console.WriteLine(xList[i] + " " + yList[i]);
}
for (int i = xList.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  Console.WriteLine(xList[i] + " " + (-yList[i]));
}
```

---

However, your calculation of the lists is wrong to start with. Using square root will not give you a curve that is circular. You need to use sinus and cosinus.

```
for (double r = 0; r < Math.PI; r += Math.PI / 20) {
  xList.Add(Math.Cos(r) * radius);
  yList.Add(Math.Sin(r) * radius);
}
```

Comment: I didn't even think about that when i posted my answer, But! assuming these are coordinates, if you are 'reversing' the coordinates, which is what i'm assuming to be happening, points that were originally negative will most likely need to become positive

Comment: with the circle algorithm y is always positive to begin with which is what the first loop gives. the y values are reversed to get one half of the circle while for the other half the y values are negated.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use Linq and replace the line with;

```
yyList.AddRange(yList.Select(num => -num));
```

Note that you'll have to add a `using`clause for Linq if you don't already have it;

```
using System.Linq;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Foreach(int x in list){x = -x};
```

Comment: that would work too. thanks. i was thinking along the lines of using linq to do it.

Comment: Can't assign to a foreach loop var.

Comment: Also `foreach` isn't capitalized.